# Why Elastic Beanstalk is trying to use aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to create template Elastic Beanstalk environment manually. when I was creating this environment I chose to create new service role "aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role". When i launched environment it failed with

```
The instance profile aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role associated with the environment does not exist.
```

I tried to create that service role manualy. but it still doesnt recgonize it.

Comment: thanks. So every time i create an elastic beanstalk service it will always look for aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role?

Comment: also, why i cant view anywhere in IAM list of instance profiles?

Comment: Why not let it auto create it? then modify it after?